# "Remerging" Git branches that have already been merged

Tags: git, merge

My coworker is extremely careless a is always over-writing my changes in Git.  So we'll have a develop branch.  I'll merge branch1 into develop, and my coworker will merge branch2 in that overwrites my changes.

Is there a way can merge branch1 back in so I can reassert my changes and resolve the conflicts?

Comment: That makes no sense. You need to fix your process, not further complicate it. If your coworker is overwriting your changes, you need to stop that. Changes should never be overwritten, whoever pushes last just resolves the conflicts. If your coworker isn't resolving conflicts correctly, that needs to be addressed at the source.

Comment: You can checkout the files from your previous commits and make a new commit, but this will overwrite changes that your coworker made.  You need to have your coworker take more care in resolving conflicts or not let them merge anymore.

Comment: @meagar I work for a business, therefore it doesn't have a process.  I need a technical solution to changes being overwritten.

Comment: @Schleis Is there a easy way to do that?  I use Sourcetree.  One the command line, would I just write checkout branch1?

I can take care to not overwrite important changes.

Comment: `git checkout branch1 -- <files that you want reverted>` will bring the changes into the branch.  Then you can make a new commit.  You definitely need to get some sort of process in place to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Joe is it possible to explain ***how*** exactly your coworker is "overwriting" your changes? Is he force-pushing to your shared branch?